# Program that provides diagrams for documentation

Tags: python

The general problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a code base that has zero documentation so I'm trying to automatically generate some diagrams of classes in package that I'm analyzing using erdantic.

Trying to make this as reusable as possible, so I have a `generate_diagrams()` function that should take in one argument, which is the package I want to iterate through.

I often feel like I throw the terms *module* and *package* around interchangeably — I might be doing it now — so I defaulted my argument to the name "directory".  But I feel that's not right since I'm not passing in a path.

Should I change the argument in `generate_diagrams()` below? What's a more accurate name?

```
import erdantic as erd
import glob
import importlib
import example.models

from os import path, makedirs


def draw_diagram(module, cls_name, output_path):
    """

    Args:
        module: module object
        cls_name: name of the class that's associated with  the module
        output_path: path where diagram to be saved

    Returns:
        void - outputs .png file at given path

    """
    try:
        diagram = erd.create(module.__getattribute__(cls_name))
        diagram.models
        diagram.draw(f"{output_path}/{cls_name}.png")

    except erd.errors.UnknownModelTypeError:
        pass


def generate_diagrams(directory):
    """

    Args:
        directory: package you have imported that contains module(s) you wish to diagram

    Returns:
        void - generates diagram using draw_diagram function

    """

    doc_path = path.dirname(__file__)
    modules = glob.glob(path.join(path.dirname(directory.__file__), "*.py"))
    module_names = [path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if path.isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]

    for module_name in module_names:

        if not path.exists(path.join(doc_path, module_name)):
            print(f'Making {module_name} directory')
            makedirs(module_name)

        module = importlib.import_module(f'{directory.__name__}.{module_name}')
        classes = dict([(name, cls) for name, cls in module.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)])

        for name, cls in classes.items():
            print(f'Drawing {module_name}.{name} diagram')
            draw_diagram(module, cls_name=name, output_path=path.join(doc_path, module_name))


def main():
    generate_diagrams(directory=example.models)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried Doxygen?

Comment: I have not. First time trying to automate diagram building. Is that the standard?

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it standard, but it's popular and well-established. I'd give that a shot before writing any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doxygen recommendation notwithstanding,

- Consider adding PEP484 type hints, particularly to the signatures of functions such as `draw_diagram`. For that method, it's not really correct Python terminology to call the return value "void" - it's `None`.
- Does the single-expression statement `diagram.models` actually have any effect? If so that deserves a comment.
- Rather than `glob.glob` consider `pathlib.Path.glob` which has some usage niceties
- `path.basename(f)[:-3]` is a very fragile way of acquiring a stem. Again, `pathlib.Path` can do a better job.

The line

```
dict([(name, cls) for name, cls in module.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)])
```

first of all should not use an inner list, since `dict` can directly accept a generator; and secondly would be better-represented as a dictionary comprehension:

```
{name: cls for name, cls in module.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)}
```

This loop:

```
    for name, cls in classes.items():
        print(f'Drawing {module_name}.{name} diagram')
        draw_diagram(module, cls_name=name, output_path=path.join(doc_path, module_name))
```

doesn't actually use `cls`, so should only iterate over the dictionary's keys, not its items.

Comment: All great suggestions. What's the protocol? Should I add an edited version of the changes? I also reconfigured to a class structure so I could add a logger to track exceptions in the draw diagram method

Comment: If you think you've gotten all that you can out of this round, and enough time has passed that it's unlikely you'll get another answer (this is a judgement call on your behalf), then accept whichever answer you think has the highest value and post a new question with your revised code. Thank you!

Comment: One last question before I accept this answer. What is your thoughts on the argument name "directory" for the generate_diagram() function? Is it more appropriately a package?

Comment: Packages are not a thing in Python - it's a module. Just as important as the name is the typehint, in this case `types.ModuleType`